# Clickable parent DIV to show and hide children DIV has problems in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

This is kind of crazy and I am not sure what's wrong. I want to make a DIV clickable to show/hide children divs. But once I do a hide of one children, I cannot unhide it.

Here's my entire code. Any help appreciated. IN example below, I cannot unhide inner1 when clicking Cancel button.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner1">
    1
    </div>

    <div class="inner2" style='display:none'>
    2 <input type='button' value='cancel' class='cancel'>
    </div>

</div>


<style>
div {border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.wrapper').live("click", function(){
            $('.inner1').hide();
            $('.inner2').show();
        });


        $('.cancel').live("click", function(){
            $('.inner1').show();
            $('.inner2').hide();
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the `click` on `.cancel` from bubbling up and *also* being a click on `.wrapper` by using [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$('.cancel').live("click", function(e){
  $('.inner1').show();
  $('.inner2').hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WL3jd/).  What's currently happening is you *are* hiding it, but then the `.wrapper` click handler gets the click and immediately shows `.inner2` again.

Comment: after some further thought, i decided just to make inner divs clickable instead. having the main div clickable presents so many challenges now that you have explained to me what's happening. thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Scott - that sounds like a better solution to me as well, cheers on getting it the way you wanted :)